# Update Choice column in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

I need update choice column. Let say my column has values like "A", "B". Now I need to insert their a new value like "C". My following code is not working.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        var spList = web.Lists[listName];
                        SPFieldChoice spChoiceField = (SPFieldChoice)spList.Fields[fieldName];
                        spChoiceField.Choices.Add(value);
                        spChoiceField.Update();
                        spList.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        return "Field has been updated with new value: " + value;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you please add details on the problem? Witch line is failing? What error message? What is the global context (i.e. where's the code running)? Why do you open new `SPSite` / `SPWeb` objects?

Comment: Beside: `spList.Update()` is definitely not needed here.

Comment: It is not give any error. I have created a workflow sandbox activity. let say my workflow is running with List "AList" under site "ASite". Now I need to update a from choice column from different list from different site. Global context is not same where I am running this code. But user who is running this code has full-control permission. I have test without spList.Update()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spChoiceField.Choices.Add(value);
```

Solved by changing above line by following

```
spChoiceField.AddChoice(value);
```